# Mocking the web browser orientationchange event to test bound event handler function with jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, orientation-changes

I have an angularjs directive to create an event handler for the orientation change event to add a classname when the orientation change is landscape (it still needs improvement so bear with me for now):

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('orientationHandler', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var className = 'mobile_landscape';
      var mediaQuery = 'only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)';
      var orientationCheck = function() {
        if ($window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
          element.addClass(className);
          $rootScope.$broadcast('Orientation.change', 'landscape');
        } else {
          element.removeClass(className);
          $rootScope.$broadcast('Orientation.change', 'portrait');
        }
      };
      $window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
          $timeout(orientationCheck, 100);
          $timeout(orientationCheck, 200);
        },
        false
      );
      $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $timeout(orientationCheck, 100);
        $timeout(orientationCheck, 200);
      });
    };
  });
```

Now I would like to test on jasmine such a directive:

```js
//TODO: Find a way to test orientation change events
describe('Directive: orientationHandler', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var element,
      scope,
      $window;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $httpBackend, _$window_) {
    $window = _$window_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<div orientation-handler></div>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).respond(200);
  }));

  it('should broadcast an event when changed the orientation', function () {
    var message;
    scope.$on('Orientation.change', function(event, value) {
      message = value;
    });
    angular.element($window).trigger('orientationchange');
    scope.$apply();
    expect(message).toBeDefined();
    expect(angular.isString(message)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

So, is there a way to programatically trigger the orientation change event, or mocking it somehow to test the bound event handler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. I would use the following to check the type of orientation:

   ```
   $window.screen.orientation.type
   ```

   There is no need to run media queries.
2. I use the following to trigger the event in my tests:

   ```
   function dispatchOrientationChangeEvent() {
     var evt, orientationEventType = 'orientationchange';
     evt = $window.document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
     evt.initEvent(orientationEventType, true, true);
     $window.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
   ```